# IntelliJ adding additional jvm parameters but where?

Tags: java, maven, encoding, intellij-idea, jvm

So this is a web application the jvm running the applications encoding must be Cp1252 to make the web - app work fine.

In .bash_profile when I add:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252"
```

and open up terminal and start jetty with:

```
mvn org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.22:run
```

everything will be fine. How do I know? There is a page which checks the encoding in the web app itself and it shows:

```
Encoding JVM: windows-1252 / Encoding Application: Cp1252
```

Now when I have the same jvm parameters in IntelliJ, I see this is added to my parameters:

```
-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12.app/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and this breaks everything.

How can I edit the parameters IntelliJ adds to maven runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create maven configuration with custom parameters. Check http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-maven-run-debug-configuration.html